# Обработка строки + sql

Tags: php, sql, строки

Здравствуйте!

У меня не получается правильно обработать строку. Мне нужно, чтобы при выводе списка имён, последняя запятая была удалена кодом.
Вот код:

```
 $sql = "SELECT `login`, `id` as `id` FROM `users` WHERE `fac`='smth' and dostup!=0 ORDER BY `id` DESC Limit 3";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
$str = "<a style='text-decoration: none; color: blue' target='_blank' href='/info.php?user=$rows[id]'>" .$rows['login']. "</a>, ";
print mb_substr($str, 0, -1);
}
```

В следствии этого кода, она убирает либо пробел, либо все запятые в случае отсутствия пробела... Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = '';
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
  $str .= '<a style="text-decoration: none; color: blue" target="_blank" href="/info.php?user=' . $rows["id"] . '">' . $rows["login"] . '</a>, ';
}

$str = trim($str, ', ');

echo $str;
```